# Some icons changed after changing username and home folder name

Tags: finder, user-account, icon

I have changed my username and home folder name in macOS Monterey and now the sidebar icons were just generic.

I unchecked and checked back all of them in Finder's preferences and all changed back except Desktop icon. I tried to remove it from the sidebar and then drag it there from my home folder but it still shows like this:

[image]

If I select get info I see the correct icon though:

[image]

Any idea how can I get the correct icon back in sidebar?

Comment: This is remarkably similar to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437406/how-can-i-restore-my-finder-sidebar-icons asked earlier today. Maybe we found a bug?

Comment: Wow, this is crazy.

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet? If not, also check out this post (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334693/custom-icons-disappeared-from-folders-in-home-directory) and see if your home folder is capitalized.